# Why does this JavaScript function work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, numbers, primes

Much apologies for the vague title, but I need to elaborate. Here is the code in question, which I read on http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/07/prime-numbers-factorial-and-fibonacci-series-with-javascript-array.html:

```
function isPrime(i) {
  return (i > 1) && Array.apply(0, Array(1 + ~~Math.sqrt(i))).
    every(function (x, y) { 
        console.log(x + ' ' + i % y);
        return (y < 2) || (i % y !== 0) 
    });
}

isPrime(23);
isPrime(19);
isPrime(188);
```

Just for fun, I added those logs so we can see some output:

```
undefined NaN
undefined 0
undefined 1
undefined 2
undefined 3
undefined NaN
undefined 0
undefined 1
undefined 1
undefined 3
undefined NaN
undefined 0
undefined 0
```

This is the first time I have every seen `apply` and `every`, so bear with me, but my understanding is that `apply` basically calls the Array function, where the first argument is the substitution for its `this` and the second is the output...Never would think that would be useful, but this function seems to work, so...

Here, they seem to be creating an array of length equal to the square root of the number in question. I suppose that makes sense because the square root would be the largest possible factor of the number in question.

OK, so from here, if we were to log that array for, say, the first number, it would look like this:

```
> var i = 23;
undefined
> Array.apply(0, Array(1 + ~~Math.sqrt(i)));
[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

Great, so it is an array of five `undefined`. Ok, fine, so from here, the `every` method is supposed to check whether every element in that array passes the callback function test (or whatever).

The Microsoft documentation specifies three possible arguments for the `every` method:

- value
- index
- array

Therefore, in this example `x` is the value, i.e. `undefined`, and `y` is the index.

Our output agrees with that conclusion. However, I'm still fuzzy about nested return statements (if the lowest one returns, does its parent also return?), the `||` operator here (if the first test passes, does the every loop stop?), and just generally how this works.

---

**EDIT**

the log should be with an x, not a y. my mistake:

```
console.log(y + ' ' + i % y); -> console.log(x + ' ' + i % y);
```

---

**EXPLANATION**

So, how did I come across this code, you ask? Well, of course, the simplest way to check for a prime in Java would be like this:

```
public static boolean isPrime(double num) {
    for (double i = 2.0; i < sqrt(num); i++) {
        if (num % i == 0.0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

or Python

```
def isPrime(num):
    x = 2
    isPrime = True
    while x < math.sqrt(num):
        if num % x == 0:
            isPrime = False
            break
        x = x + 1
    return isPrime
```

or js

```
function isPrime(n) {
    for (var i = 2.0; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n % i === 0.0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

But say I wanted to check for the largest prime factor of a number like `600851475143` These looping methods would take too long, right? I think this "hack", as we are describing it, may be even less efficient, because it is using arrays instead of integers or floats, but even still, I was just looking for a more efficient way to solve that problem.

Comment: I definitely do not get the same `console.log()` output as you, and I'm not surprised. `y` should never be `undefined`.

Comment: The blog where you found that has a whole article about that `Array()` trick.

Comment: Yep, I read the blog, but got stuck on this part. Cannot figure it out, so came here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in that post is basically crap. Teaching people to write code while simultaneously using hacks is garbage. Yes, hacks have their place (optimization), but educators should demonstrate solutions that don't depend on them.

Hack 1

```
// the 0 isn't even relevant here. it should be null
Array.apply(0, Array(1 + ...))
```

Hack 2

```
// This is just Math.floor(x), but trying to be clever  
~~x
```

Hack 3

```
// this is an outright sin; totally unreadable code
// I bet most people don't know the binding precedence of % over +
y + ' ' + i % y

// this is evaluated as
y + ' ' + (i % y)

// example
2 + ' ' + (5 % 2) //=> "2 1"
```

---

> I'm still fuzzy about nested return statements (if the lowest one returns, does its parent also return?),

No. A `return` only return the function the statement exists in

> the || operator here (if the first test passes, does the every loop stop?)

No. `Array.prototype.every` will return `false` as soon as the callback returns a `false`. If a `false` is never returned from the callback, `.every` will return `true.

```
function isEven(x) { return x % 2 === 0; }
[2,4,5,6].every(isEven); //=> false, stops at the 5
[2,4,6].every(isEven);   //=> true
```

Here's an example of `.every` short circuiting

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].every(x=> {console.log(x, x<4); return x<4;});
// 1 true
// 2 true
// 3 true
// 4 false
//=> false
```

See how it stops once the callback returns `false`? Elements `5` and `6` aren't even evaluated.

> ... and just generally how this works.

`&&` kind of works like `Array.prototype.every` and `||` kind of works like `Array.prototype.some`.

`&&` will return `false` as soon as the first `false` is encountered; in other words, it expects ***every*** arguments to be `true`.

`||` will return `true` as soon as the first `true` is encountered; in other words, it expects only ***some*** argument to be `true`.

Relevant: [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: Agree with the *crap* characterization. It's kind-of a clever trick, but it violates the First Rule of Posting Sample Code On Your Blog: the worse the code is, the greater the number of people who'll embed it into software that may someday be critical to your survival.

Comment: Well, then why doesn't each index-of-0 member return true on `(y < 2)`?

Comment: I mean, the only reason I came to this blog was because the for loop I was using to check for prime factors of a number posted on the Euler Project was taking too long.

Comment: @pward It does return `true` on `y < 2` - it doesn't want to bother to check whether the numbers are divisible by 0 or 1.

Comment: @pward this code is no more efficient than any other brute-force prime test. If you want it to be fast, you need to build a seive.

Comment: @Pointy The code was presumably written to show the "power" of high-level array functions like `every`, not as a practical prime-testing method.

Comment: I don't feel as bad about this code as I do about some of the clever "reduce" hacks I frequently see posted in answers.

Comment: @Barmar oh sure, I agree with that, but I'm just speaking from experience. Stuff like that needs to be marked with caveats if you care about how innocent people might interpret it :)

Comment: @naomik The output still prints all those zeros and then stuff after, right? so the flow got there and kept going...

Comment: @pward every will continue so long a the callback return `true`. I've provided an edit to the `every` section which shows this conclusively.